# Use CodeIgniter auto-loaded model in view

Tags: view, model, autoloader, codeigniter-3

In the header of my site I have to add some meta-tags that are stored in the database. I have created a *Metatag* model and made it auto-loadable in *autoload.php*.

This model will provide all the meta-tags and they will be inserted in the header of all views, of any route. Can the model's meta-tags array (retrieved from the table) be somehow directly and globally used in the view or do I have to create it in every controller then pass it to the view through `$data`?

I have quite a few controllers and I would like to avoid requesting the meta-tags in each of them, specially when the model is auto-loaded globally.

Answer (score 0):

I do not think there was any other way than to go through the controller . If that were the case, the MVC pattern would no longer respect what goes against the rule CodeIgniter .